# How to allow client to change their API base URL in iOS app without changing the app code?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, plist

I'm developing an iOS app for a client that integrates with the client's API, I define the API base URL in the singleton object used to interface with the API.

```
#define kAPIBaseURL @"https://myAPIURL.com/api/"
```

the client would like to change the API Base URL by themselves instead of having me change the URL in the app code every time.

I distribute the build to the client via test flight or send them an IPA file, not the code base.

What is the best way to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the best way to do this would be to use something like parse and pull the API urls from there. Then they can update it one the fly via the parse console.

Comment: Why did someone down vote me for this. This is beyond a valid answer. In fact, I've used this technique in production applications. The Parse SDK will cache and handle updating/syncing the URLs for you. You have to be kidding me if you don't believe this is valid or a 'good' methodology lol.

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1:

- Create a key ("kAPIBaseURL") in NSUserdefaults and set its value to the default APIURL. Advantage of NSUserdefaults is that it persists even accross app updates (until app is deleted). Don't forget to call NSUserdefaults synchronize immediately after you write something in NSUserdefaults!
- in your delegate, everytime app didfinishlaunchingwithoptions (less often) or when app did become active (more often), send a request to a webservices of your own that holds the current up to date API Base URL
- return to your app the latest up to date API Base URL.
- Compare existing value for kAPIBaseURL in NSUserdefaults and update it if it differs.

If you don't want to use webservices, just store a .json file somewhere on a ftp containing the  base url and make a request against that file directly. Customers will need access to that ftp to udpate the file.

JSON file content example:

```
{"baseURL":"http://www.mybaseurl.com/"}
```

Solution 2 (not recommended):

- Build a middle man: set kAPIBaseURL to a url that only job is to make a redirection (maybe htaccess) towards the real server.
- That's faster to implement but it will make every single request from the app slowlier.

Comment: What if the client changes the API base URL after the app is launched? the app will still use the old API base URL.

Comment: The app will use the old API base until the app is relaunched (if you put code in appdidfinishlaunching) or until app enters foreground again (for appdidbecomeactive).
If you want realtime solution, you need to use realtime events (leveraging websockets, see socketIO) but that would be heavily overengineered. 
Other solution would be to send the new base url through a remote push notification (you can send any data you want in the alert payload and interpret it from the app delegate).

Comment: Like I said, ask a proper question. Instead of waiting for different answers and then adding extra information each time that then makes the answer incorrect.

Comment: @Fogmeister I'm not sure what you're reading... but he/she did ask a pretty valid and self explanatory question from the get go... It wasn't hard to interpret what his/her needs are.

Comment: Where does it say that they need to distribute the new url via then network? Where does it say that providing a variable for the user to update is not valid? You have massively over complicated quite a simple thing.

Comment: @Fogmeister He's asking how to enable a client to update the API calls on the fly. That's self explanatory (especially in the programatical world). Updating on the fly usually means implementing a type of endpoint the client can manipulate via a dashboard or something that will sync information to the app. That's a pretty standard practice.... So I'm not sure where your confusion and frustration lies, but it is not validated here.

Comment: @Fogmeister And as reference, here's the simple line of text the questioner has posted to describe the needs: "the client would like to change the API Base URL by themselves instead of having me change the URL in the app code every time.". That's pretty much all that's needed.

Comment: @TheGamingArt I suppose it depends on the app and use. I had an app that had to be able to connect to various different base urls based on the project it was currently connected to. The app had a way of changing the base URL so that it could be configured for its specific project. This question could be used 100% for that app. There is nothing about the question that states it is any different from this. Where (for instance) is there any mention of changing the Base URL via a dashboard or anything similar? If you had given that answer for the app I worked on it wouldn't have worked.

Answer (score 0):

### Make Use of DNS Server

Use domain name instead of IP address.

And build application using domain name like http://domainname.com/api

If you're changing the IP address it will automatically redirected from DNS server.